# Sequence of unit vectors in a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

**Question:** Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $\{\xi_{i}\}\subset H$ be a sequence of unit vectors.  Suppose that $||T_{j}(\xi_{i})-\xi_{i}||\rightarrow0$ as $i\rightarrow\infty$, for $j=1, 2, ...n$ (here $T_{j}\in B(H)$). Then can we get that 
$$\frac{1}{n}||\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}T_{j}(\xi_{i})||\geq 1?$$

Comment: By "can we get that $[\ldots]$", are you asking if $[\ldots]$ is possibly true, or are you asking if $[\ldots]$ is necessarily true?

Comment: Also what is $n$?? Are you asking if this can be true for *all* $n$?  For a single $n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $T_j=T:\ell^2\to \ell^2$ for all $j$ where $Tx=x$ and let $\xi _i=e_i$ in $\ell^2$. Then $\|\sum_{j=1}^{n} Te_j\|_2=\sqrt {n}$ and $\frac {\sqrt {n}}{n}< 1$.

Comment: By $L^2$ you mean the space of sequences, yes?  I have normally seen this as $\ell^2$ (`\ell^2`).

Comment: @Goos yes. i mean $\ell^2$.

Comment: @Mitsos Thanks, Mitsos :P

Answer (score 1):

The statement in your question
$$
\frac{1}{n}||\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}T_{j}(\xi_{i})||\geq 1
$$
could be true for all $n$ or could even be false for all $n$.  The hypotheses you state are not enough to determine.

- Mitsos' answer gives an example of this being false for all $n$.
- Let $H = \mathbb{R}$, $\xi_i = 1$, and $T_j(xi_i) = 1 + \frac{1}{n}$.  Then $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^n T_j(\xi_i) > n$, so your statement is true for all $n$.

The presence of linear operators in your question is a red herring, because  $T_j(\xi_i)$ can essentially be any elements of $H$ you feel like.  This seems to be implied by [this version of the Hahn-Banach theorem](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2001-129-10/S0002-9939-01-06037-3/S0002-9939-01-06037-3.pdf).